# Testing Nodejs with Coffeescript

Tags: unit-testing, node.js, tdd, coffeescript, acceptance-testing

I'm dabbling with node.js and coffeescript and I want to know what is a good unit test and acceptance test setup for the technologies.  The data component of the project (backend/webserver/database) is using coffeescript and node.js and the view and component is going to be in coffeescript/javascript (using titanium appcelerator) and they are very separate but if they can use the same testing frameworks for both it would be cool.

The names I have heard after a bit of searching are Jasmine, Zombie and Mocha.

Any help would be appreciated Thanks.

UPDATE:

I forgot to add I'm used to developing using rails and using rspec for unit tests and Cucumber for acceptance tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mocha](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/), [Vows](http://ariejan.net/2011/06/10/vows-and-coffeescript), and [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) are the most well known. (I haven't heard of Zombie). Which one to use is kind of an opinion question. We found Vows to be pretty heavyweight. Jasmine moved in a better direction, but Mocha is doing the job for now. We've had decent success with Mocha for BDD style unit tests. Here's [an example](https://github.com/JosephJNK/Scout/blob/master/domain/scout/services/specs/getWhenConstructedWithStrategies.spec.coffee):

```
Scout = require '../../Scout'
FilteringStrategy = require '../../models/filteringStrategies/FilteringStrategy'
FormattingStrategy = require '../../models/formattingStrategies/FormattingStrategy'
RetrievalStrategy = require '../../models/retrievalStrategies/RetrievalStrategy'
EchoInputStrategy = require '../../models/retrievalStrategies/EchoInputStrategy'
CdrStrategy = require './mocks/CdrStrategy'
EveryOtherStrategy = require './mocks/EveryOtherStrategy'
ArrayToStringStrategy = require './mocks/ArrayToStringStrategy'

require 'should'

describe 'When constructed with a custom retrieval technique', ->
  describe '#get', ->
    it 'should return results', (done)->
      data = [0..10]
      connectionScout = new Scout(CdrStrategy)

      connectionScout.get data, (results)->
        results.should.eql [1..10]
        done()
```

It doesn't appear that there's any fully integrated Cucumber-esque business-readable DSL type of tool for NodeJS and Coffeescript yet.

Comment: I'm a big fan of using Mocha for unit tests and Zombie.js for end-to-end browser testing.

Comment: According to [cucumber.js](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/): "Both JavaScript (.js) and CoffeeScript (.coffee) source files are supported."

Answer (score 0):

I use Jasmine and it works for me, you can write all testcases by coffeescript.